# Easy setup wizard for Ruby-on-Rails app + web server on windows

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, installation

I'm developing a Ruby-on-Rails app which uses MS SQL Server db.  I will need to automate the deployment to Windows servers because it will be distributed through different channels and the setup needs to be as automatic as possible.  I have read that IIS is not a good solution so the setup process would need to install a web server (apache, Nginx or thin).  I haven't used JRuby but I have heard it might make matters simpler on Windows.
Is there any good resources, software packages or suggestions on how this can be solved?

Johann

Comment: I've not used it myself, but [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) sounds like it could be useful for this type of thing.